# How can I keep the main navigation highlighted while navigating to different sub/sibling pages?

Tags: ember.js

How can I keep the main navigation highlighted while navigating to different sub/sibling pages? My app has sibling pages with shared sub navigation:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('charts', {path: 'charts'}, function(){
        this.resource('chart-index', {path: 'index'});
        this.resource('chart-archive', {path: 'archive'});
    });
});
```

My templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div>
        {{#link-to "chart-index" class="tab-item"}}
            Charts
        {{/link-to}}
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="charts">
    <div>
        {{#link-to 'chart-index' class="control-item"}}
            Latest Chart
        {{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to 'chart-archive' class="control-item"}}
            Chart Archive
        {{/link-to}}
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="chart-index">
    index
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="chart-archive">
    archive
</script>
```

But since the main navigation link to chart-index, it looses the highlighting when I hit chart-archive. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kitsunde/mMYKp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you need to link to the index route directly. You should be able to link the parent resource for `charts` directly and Ember will auto route you to the ChartsIndex Route.

From [the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/):

> Transitioning to posts or creating a link to posts is equivalent to transitioning to posts.index or linking to posts.index

Haven't tested this but that should ensure your "active" class is applied.

Comment: Ah, that works wonderfully. The parent nav is linked to `charts` and the subnav is linked to `charts.index`. Wonderful. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kitsunde/mMYKp/4/